# In html posting a form with javascript and php validation.. one fault- return true or false goes into text box of form

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, post

The form works, except, the value of true or false, gets put into the 'messagetxt' and that is the message I receive through email. I found the easiest way to create a continual alert box for invalid data, was to create a second contact page with an automatic alert upon loading.

```
    //this is on page contact.html
//head etc..
<body>
<form  action="email.php" method="post" name="contact" >
          First Name:
          <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" id="fname" />
          Last Name:
          <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname" id="lname"/>
          Email Address:
          <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email"  id="email"/>
          Message:
          <input type="text" placeholder="Message" name="messagetxt" id="messagetxt"/>
          <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
  var inputElem = document.getElementById('fname'); 
        var inputElem = document.getElementById('lname');
          var inputElem = document.getElementById('email');
            var inputElem = document.getElementById('messagetxt');
             var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
form.onsubmit = function (){
if (inputElem.value = '' || inputElem.value.length < 1){
        alert('Please complete all fields'); 
        return false; 
    }
};
</script>
</body>
</html>


//===
//this is on a page contacterror.html
//head etc..
<body>
<form  action="email.php" method="post" name="contact" >
          First Name:
          <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" id="fname" />
          Last Name:
          <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname" id="lname"/>
          Email Address:
          <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email"  id="email"/>
          Message:
          <input type="text" placeholder="Message" name="messagetxt" id="messagetxt"/>
          <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
  var inputElem = document.getElementById('fname'); 
        var inputElem = document.getElementById('lname');
          var inputElem = document.getElementById('email');
            var inputElem = document.getElementById('messagetxt');
             var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
form.onsubmit = function (){
if (inputElem.value = '' || inputElem.value.length < 1){
        alert('Please complete all fields'); 
        return false; 
    }
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Please complete all fields");
</script>
</body>
</html>


//===
//this is my email.php
<body>
<?php

function spamcheck($field)
  {
  //filter_var() sanitizes the e-mail
  //address using FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL
  $field=filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

  //filter_var() validates the e-mail
  //address using FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL
  if(filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
    return TRUE;
    }
  else
    {
    return FALSE;
    }
  }

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {


    //process form data
  //check if the email address is invalid
  $mailcheck = spamcheck($_POST['email']);
  if ($mailcheck==FALSE)
    {
    header ("Location:contacterror.html");
            }

else
      {
  //send email
  $email=$_POST['email'];
  $fname=$_POST['fname'];
  $lname=$_POST['lname'];
  $message = $_POST['messagetxt'] ;
  $subject="website contact";
  mail("contact@yve3.com", $subject ,$message , "From: $email");
  echo "Thank you for using our mail form.";
  }

  }
else
  {//if "email" is not filled out, display the form
   header ("Location:contacterror.html");
        }

include ("contact.html");

?>
</body>
```

Is anybody able to help?

Comment: `if (inputElem.value == '' ||` ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to take a look at your javascript. It seems to be causing the message textbox to return false upon reloading the page. If you remove the javascript or place it in the head of your page, this should take care of the issue. Also, the variable inputElem should be changed for each element that you want to retrieve. Your variable is overwriting itself everytime you call getElementById(). Try something like this:

```
    <!doctype>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function Validate()
        {
            // create array containing textbox elements
            var inputs = [document.getElementById('fname'), document.getElementById('lname'), document.getElementById('email'), document.getElementById('messagetxt')];

            var error;

            for(var i = 0; i<inputs.length; i++)
            // loop through each element to see if value is empty
            {
                if(inputs[i].value == '')
                {
                    error = 'Please complete all fields.';
                }
            }
            if(error)
            {
                alert(error);
                return false;
            }
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action='email.php' method="POST" name="contact" >
          First Name:
          <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" id="fname" />
          Last Name:
          <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname" id="lname"/>
          Email Address:
          <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email"  id="email"/>
          Message:
          <input type="text" placeholder="Message" name="messagetxt" id="messagetxt"/>
          <input type="submit" value="submit" onClick="return Validate();"/>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

use      `<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>`

and also replace

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
```

with

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

First `if` check if your form method is `POST`. it does not necessary mean if the user submit the form with pressing `submit` button.but the second `if` check if the user really submit the form with pressing `submit` button

Answer (score 2):

I rectified my code, with thanks to Steel and Amir, this is neater, less complicated and works.

I thought I'd post this, as it is useful for others.

This provides a client and server side check against spamming the email address.
I've removed excess error handling, removed the extra html, forcing an error alert.

```
//javascript in head with loop to check fields 

 <script type="text/javascript">    
        function Validate()
        {
            // create array containing textbox elements
            var inputs = [document.getElementById('fname'), document.getElementById('lname'), document.getElementById('email'), document.getElementById('messagetxt')];    
            var error;

            for(var i = 0; i<inputs.length; i++)
            // loop through each element to see if value is empty
            {
                if(inputs[i].value == '')
                {
                    error = 'Please complete all fields.';
                }
            }
            if(error != null)
            {
              alert(error);
                return false;
            }
        }
</script>
</head>    

//amended form
<body>
<form  action="email.php" method="post" name="contact" >
          First Name:
          <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" id="fname" />
          Last Name:
          <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname" id="lname"/>
          Email Address:
          //===
          // input type 'email' - client side check for spam
          <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email"  id="email"/>
          Message:
          <input type="text" placeholder="Message" name="messagetxt" id="messagetxt"/>
          <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" onclick="Validate ()" />
        </form>

        </body>
</html>

//amended php

<body>
<?php

//==
//server side check for spam
function spamcheck($field)
  {
  //filter_var() sanitizes the e-mail
  //address using FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL
  $field=filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

  //filter_var() validates the e-mail
  //address using FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL
  if(filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
    return TRUE;
    }
  else
    {
    return FALSE;
    }
  }

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    //process form data
  //check if the email address is invalid
  $mailcheck = spamcheck($_POST['email']);
 if ($mailcheck==TRUE){

  //send email
  $email=$_POST['email'];
  $fname=$_POST['fname'];
  $lname=$_POST['lname'];
  $message = $_POST['messagetxt'] ;
  $subject="website contact";
  mail("contact@yve3.com", $subject ,$message , "From: $email");
  echo "Thank you for using our mail form.";
 }}

include ("contact.html");

?>
</body>
</html>
```